# How to break a Numpy ndarray into blocks

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I'm trying to break an array of an image (size 160 x 160) into blocks of 8 x 8 so that I can perform DCT algorithm on each block. I am very unsure how to approach this. The shape and values are shown here

```
    print(arrayY.shape)
    print(arrayY)

(160, 160)
[[ 68  68  67 ...,  89  96  91]
 [ 69  69  68 ...,  93  99  95]
 [ 70  70  71 ...,  99  99  98]
 ..., 
 [ 86  84  83 ...,  84  99 103]
 [ 79  79  77 ...,  82  87 102]
 [ 75  75  74 ...,  92  92  99]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Just what output do you want from that input? Do you want a 20 x 20 array where each item is an 8 x 8 array or do you want something else? Please show the desired output from that example input.

Comment: yea exactly what you just said